# Correct way to use memset() on multi dimensional array of type enum

Tags: c, arrays, enums

I have been struggling to get memset to work for me.

I have the following array type:

```
typedef enum cell game_board[BOARDHEIGHT][BOARDWIDTH];
```

Cell enum:

```
enum cell
{
   C_EMPTY,
   ...
}
```

But when I call `memset()` to initialize all values in the board to `C_EMPTY`. Nothing seems to happen:

```
void init(game_board board)
{
   memset(board, C_EMPTY, sizeof(board) * BOARDHEIGHT * BOARDHEIGHT);
}
```

I have tried many different ways of calling `memset()` but I think the problem is in my understanding.

Comment: Define Nothing seems to happen?

Comment: after I call my init method and check against a position in the array `board[0][0] == C_EMPTY ` it is never true

Comment: Post a minimal self-contained example please.

Comment: @iharob has clarified it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set an integer value that way, `memset()` sets a byte at a time, an integer is usually 4 bytes. In the particular case you posted it will set all to `0` since it's `0` it works. But with non-`zero` values it will not work correctly.

Comment: So because C_EMPTY is the first value in my enum it should work but trying to set it to another enum value it will not work? Sorry, very new to C.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because `C_EMPTY` will be `0` in that case.

Comment: So the best way to init the array to another value would be to loop over the 2D array setting each value to whatever value I need? Another Question: What if the enum was a char enum? So `C_EMPTY = ' ', C_CROSS = 'X'`. Memset would then not work at all, correct?

Comment: *So the best way* -> NO, it's the ONLY way.